# mongo command in kubernetes manifest

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am trying to run a command in mongo deployment file like below -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-container
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: mongo
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data/db
        command:
          - "bash"
          - "-c"
          - |
            mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').createUser({user : \"$user123\", pwd  : \"$pass\", roles: [ { role: 'root', db: 'admin' } ]});"
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-pv-claim
```

as you can see i want to given access control for multiple users in command,
but i get the following error in pods logs and pods goes into error state -

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-09-21T15:42:39.549+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-09-21T15:42:39.550+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2019-09-21T15:42:39.550+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

any idea why i keep getting this?

Thanks

Comment: When you added `command`, you replaced the command that starts the database with your command that tries to connect the database. Since the database never started, you cannot connect. You can try something like this: 1) start the db in the background, 2) do your thing, 3) shutdown the db, 4) start the db in foreground as it is done in the original image.

Comment: About point (4), where do I get that info?

Comment: Go to dockerhub, find the mongodb image, and select the tag you're using. That should take you to the dockerfile for that tag. The CMD line will give you how it runs the db.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-container
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: mongo
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data/db
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          value: user
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-pv-claim
```

It will create user `user` and password `password` for `admin` database, you can find more on [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo).